# Understanding order of vectors in cross product

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that if I have 2 vectors `A, B`, then the following holds:

```
AxB = -BxA
```

If I have several vectors though, say, `A,B,C,D`, is the following correct?

```
AxBxCxD = BxAxDxC
```

I'm trying to understand how the sign changes when we switch the vectors order

Comment: Yes, you are right: $a\times b \times c\times d  = (a\times b) \times( c\times d) = (-b\times a) \times(- d\times a) = b\times b\times d  \times a$. In general the final sign corresponds to $(-1)^{s}$ where $s$ is the number of permutations you have done. In your case $s=2$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! : )

Comment: Cross product is not associative. In general, $a\times(b\times(c\times d)),\,a\times((b\times c)\times d),\,(a\times(b\times c))\times d,\,((a\times b)\times c)\times d$ and $(a\times b)\times(c\times d)$ are all different. Your question is ambiguous and cannot be answered properly if you don't specify the order of multiplication on each side of the alleged equality.

Answer (score 1):

What definition of cross product do you have?

We can define the cross product of vectors U= 'ai+ bj+ ck and V= pi+ qi+ rj as $U\times V= \left|\begin{array}{ccc} i & j & k \\ a & b & c \\ p & q & r \end{array}\right|= (br- cq)i- (ar- cp)j+ (aq- bp)k$

while $V\times U= \left|\begin{array}{ccc} i & j & k \\ p & q & r \\ a & b & c \end{array}\right|= (cq- br)i- (cp- ar)j+ (bp- aq)k= -U\times V$